# [c++ windows]capturing mouse click event from a window that isn't mine

Tags: c++, windows, events, mouse, message-loop

I want to detect when the mouse is pressed on my wallpaper.
So I got the wallpaper handle and now I'm trying to add a message loop to it, but its not working for some reason.

Here's my code so far:

```
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpszArgument, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWallPaper = getWallPaperHWND();

    if (hWallPaper != NULL)
    {

        MSG msg;
        while (GetMessage(&msg, hWallPaper, 0, 0))
        {
            MessageBox(NULL, "msg", "got message", MB_OK);
        }


    }
    else
        MessageBox(NULL,"Window wasn't found","window not found",MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Why isn't it showing a message box when I fire an even on the wallpaper, like when I click on it or even just move the mouse?

Comment: Sorry. Fixed it for you :)

Comment: Only the thread that creates the window can retrieve messages for it. Your question title says you want to capture messages for a window you don't own. So you can't use a message loop, you will have to use a hook instead. Look at `SetWindowsHookEx()` or `SetWinEventHook()` for that.

Comment: I will, thanks alot!